# 'Your PC/Device needs to be repaired' after disassembling laptop

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot

So I decided to disassemble my laptop (Asus). I just unplugged HDD and then put it back. And then when I tried to turn on my laptop, I get an error 'Your PC/Device needs to be repaired'. Can unplugging and then putting back HDD cause this problem? If so, then why?

P.S. I have Windows 10 installed
[image]

Comment: Boot repair (F1) might be able to fix it. Have you tried yet? // This error means that the Windows Boot Manager boot entry is somehow corrupted/no longer valid.

Comment: @DanielB usually removing and putting back HDD is not supposed to cause any error, right?

Comment: That’s correct. However, it could have somehow changed the drive ID as detected by the firmware or whatever.